# Restarting active query in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

For example, if ı have lines like this:

```
$this->db->where("blabla",$blala);
```

And following this line, I decided not to use this where clause (in runtime) and start doing a query from scratch. How can I disregard this where clause in active record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try

```
$this->db->_reset_select();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

This is a logical problem which you have to make sense of.

Instead of saying

```
$this->db->where('blabla', $blala);
if($dont_use_where_clause) {
  //something to ignore the where cause which CI doesn't provides anyway
}
```

That's like starting your car and trying to get back the fuel you used to start it with.
You would have to do something more logical like this:

```
if(!$dont_use_where_clause) {
  $this->db->where('blabla', $blala);
}
```

This makes sense, because it's the logical way of doing those things. That's like saying 'if I don't want to use fuel, don't start the car'. Get it?