# modify and redo last query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Can I get last query made with active record class and modify some parts of it and redo that query in codeigniter. I am trying to get total pages for my pagination. I can't directly write my query because it is dynamically created on runtime within some for loops and if statements depending on the form submitted to the page.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093370/restarting-active-query-in-codeigniter

Comment: @Repox These two question covers related but different topics. I don't think this is a duplicate of the question you mention.

Comment: The two questions appear very related in any case. Any reason why you aren't responding to the answers you get? In any of the questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you run your query twice because of the total pages? If yes, check `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `FOUND_ROWS()` in SQL.

```
$this->db->select("SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROwS id",false);
$this->db->any_AR_function(....);
$this->db->limit(...);
$result = $this->db->get();
```

After this you can call this:

```
$this->db->select("FOUND_ROWS() as count",false);
$count = $this->db->get();
```

I hope this is what you want.

Comment: This is indeed exactly what I have wanted. Do I need to put table name in get part?

Comment: In the latest call (`FOUND_ROWS() as count`) doesn't need. In the first query (`any_AR_function`) you should. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Answer (score 0):

You can get last query using:

```
$last_query = $this->db->last_query();
```

You can modify this query and then do:

```
$query = $this->db->query($modified_query);
foreach($query->result() as $row)
{

}
```